# typeahead.js for multiple json paramater

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

How to use typeahead.js using this sample response json?

```
"data": {"id":"3","title":"Activities","slug":"","code":"","published":"0"},{"id":"2","title":"Domestic","slug":"","code":"","published":"0"},{"id":"1","title":"International","slug":"","code":"","published":"0"]
```

Here is my code integrating with backbone.js. This code works before on bootstrap 2 but when I update the version to bootstrap 3 I need to modify this code and add a separate js for typehead.js and this code is not working anymore. Can someone help me to fix this issue or suggest a better results

```
var TypeAheadCollection = Backbone.Collecti.on.extend({model: Options});
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'title',
            displayKey: 'title',
           // source: substringMatcher(states)
            source: function (query, process) {
                queryAttributes = {};
                queryAttributes['searchVal'] = query;
                var list = [];

                $.ajax({
                    url: that.collection.paginator_core.url,
                    data: queryAttributes,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        typeAheadCollection = new TypeAheadCollection(response.data);
                        console.log(typeAheadCollection.pluck('title'));
                        return process(typeAheadCollection.pluck('title'));
                    }
                });                
            }
        });
```

I put console.log to check the display data. When you type a word "a" on input form there are a results on log ["Activities", "International"] and there is a drop-down but the word displaying are two undefined on both words. I expect Activities and International. I suspect the problem is within the "process()"

Answer (score 0):

The display key takes the name of the item within the object you would want to display. At the moment it is set to display 'value' which does not exist.

Comment: i change it to title and it's not working.. there is a display dropdown but the word is undefined..

Comment: So are you saying that the dropdown list appears but all the items come up as undefined? I had that issue because of the displayKey and not having unique IDs, but it doesn't appear to be the issue with you.

Comment: I update my question. when you type word "a" there are log displaying  ["Activities", "International"]  but on drop-down display two undefined.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 3 right now just want to know if my code is flexible on this version. The code above is from Bootstrap 2.1.0 up to 2.3.2.

Comment: Ohh right, you need to return the object. Typeahead expects an Array of Objects. So you should be returning [{title: "Activities"}, {title: "International"}]

Comment: Well I'm not sure what typeAheadCollection.pluck('title') does, but that appears to just return an array of names. Try to see if you can do something with that.